# Solving system of equations with zeros on diagonal

Tags: pde, finite-element, linear-solver, sparse-matrix

I am using finite elements, Newton Raphson technique and MUMPS direct solver, to solve for $P$ in this equation:

$$\frac{\delta K}{\delta x} \frac{\delta P}{\delta x}= \frac{\delta K B}{\delta x} + A$$

$A$ and $B$ are constant parameters. $K$ is a parameter varying over space. $P$ is the solution variable.

$K$ is distributed like this:

[image]

Thus, $K$ becomes zero! So I'll have zeros on the diagonal of my matrix and the solver will eventually print out that the matrix is singular.

Are there any techniques to still solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Scicomp.SE! This doesn't look like a well-posed problem to me -- can you give us a bit of background? Where does this equation come from? (I suspect it's actually not the equation you really want to (or should) solve...)

Comment: Indeed. If you think about it, *any* value for $\delta P/\delta x$ multiplied by zeros will be a solution of your problem as long as the right hand side is zero at these locations as well. That you can't solve these equations is not the fault of MUMPS, but because you're looking at nonsensical equations.